# Convert low resolution Image into High resolution Image in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How to Convert a low quality Image into High quality Image in Adobe Photoshop?? Anyone Helps!!!!!

Comment: in addition to the above a search for enlarge finds lots of other questions that may help you: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=enlarging

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. High-res contain much more information than low-res, this is why you can't upscale raster image without quality loss.